# How to add a prefix/suffix to a subset of column names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})

# Add prefix
df[['col2']] = df[['col2']].add_prefix('hi_')

print(df)
```

My desired output

I would expect the columns to change. However they have not. Why is this and how can I achieve what I want?

Why I expect this to work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
df[['col2']] = df[['col2']] * 2

print(df)
# col2 is now multiplied
```

My desired output is a dataframe with changed column names

Answer (score 0):

When you perform:

```
df[['col2']].add_prefix('hi_') * 2
```

This outputs a DataFrame with a single column:

```
   hi_col2
0        8
1       10
2       12
```

When you assign, only the values are changed:

```
df[['col2']] = df[['col2']].add_prefix('hi_') * 2

   col1  col2
0     1     8
1     2    10
2     3    12
```

Similarly using a Series:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].rename('hi_') * 2

   col1  col2
0     1     8
1     2    10
2     3    12
```

You cannot directly update values AND change the name of a column in a single operation.

Cheating a bit you could do:

```
df['hi_col2'] = df.pop('col2')*2

   col1  hi_col2
0     1        8
1     2       10
2     3       12
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not looking to do both. I just want to add a prefix to a subset of the df :D

Comment: The Q is a bit confusing. I think that the OP misunderstands the purpose of `add_prefix` (which indeed is to prefix **labels**). The OP is looking for `df['col2'] = 'hi_' + df['col2'].astype(str)`, giving the multiplication as a reason for thinking that `add_prefix` could be applied in the same way (and lead to a "similar" result: `hi_4`, etc.).

Comment: @ouroboros1 I hadn't seen it this way, but it's possible. Roger, can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: @mozway I'm sorry for the confusion. My expected output would be the original values with the column name changed (not the values in the columns). So I'm not looking to change the values, just to change the column names of a subset of the columns

Comment: @RogerKint which is what I discussed in my answer. This is not possible unless you use the trick in the end with `pop`

Comment: @RogerKint because here I added `*2`, of you remove it, it won't charge the values. But in this case better use `rename`